# Jquery Mobile 1.2 Multiple Checkbox Selection Issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm coding a Jquery Mobile 1.2, Jquery 1.8.2, css, and HTML 5 based app that I need to allow the user to select multiple images and execute a command.

The following works if I do NOT use the jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js library:

CSS Code:

```
.image-checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}

.image-checkbox-container img{
    border: 0;
    margin: 4px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<span class="image-checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="black-box" value="1" />
<img src="dummyimage1.jpg" />
</span>
<span class="image-checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="red-box" value="1" />
    <img src="dummyimage2.jpg" />
</span>
<span class="image-checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" name="green-box" value="1" />
    <img src="dummyimage3.jpg" />
</span>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.image-checkbox-container img').live('click', function(){
    if(!$(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked")){
    $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
     this.style.border = '4px solid #38A';
     this.style.margin = '0px';
}else{
        $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
    this.style.border = '0';
    this.style.margin = '4px';
}
});
```

As soon as I add in the jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js library to the code it does not function correctly anymore.  The unchecking/unselecting of the checkboxes does not work.

I attempted to use the checkboxradio("refresh") but did not have any luck.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What about using a CSS solution?**
Add additionally this custom CSS:

```
 .checked {
    border : 4px solid #38A!important;
    margin : 0px!important;
 }
```

and use this script:

```
 <script>
  $('.image-checkbox-container img').live('click', function(){
    $this=$(this);
    if($this.hasClass('checked')===true){
      $this.removeClass('checked');
    }else{
      $this.addClass('checked');
    }
  });
  </script>
```